# exit and delete all but the latest docker container

Tags: docker, containers

I currently have a lot of docker containers running that are no longer used.
So many actually that it would take a while to exit and quit them all manually.

I was wondering if there was a way to exit and delete all of them **except** for the latest one ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A quick approach to do this is the following:

First, stop all containers with this command:

`docker stop $(docker ps -aq)`

Then, start the container that you want to keep using:

`docker start container_name`

And finally, use [docker container prune](https://docs.docker.com/engine/reference/commandline/container_prune/), which removes all stopped containers.

`docker container prune`

Comment: thank you, this worked perfectly, only thing i had to change was instead of doing `docker ps -a $(docker ps -aq)`, doing `docker stop $(docker ps -a -q)`